# Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 10 on Intel Optane based computers

Tags: dual-boot

I am seeing some of the threads like this which are not fully resolved/closed.
I am getting this [computer](https://www.costco.com/Dell-XPS-Tower---Intel-Core-i7---6GB-NVIDIA-Graphics.product.100380443.html).

and want to install Ubuntu on this PCIe NVME SSD like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07418TS9P).

I am okay for a slow boot of bootloader but once I am linux...it's all faster PCIe NVME SSD.

Any suggestions/pointers?

Comment: Optane is simply Intel RST in disguise which was limited to 64GB SSD (usually mSata half card) acceleration per HDD. Pour all your money into NVMe and forget about Optane if geeky speeds are your concern. That said I went the geeky rouet and went NVMe over regular SSD but you really can't feel the difference in real life. Also you will have some problems with bleeding-edge technology like NVMe M.2 Gen 3.0 x 4 SSD but most of the kinks are worked out now. BTW hardware questions and opinions are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendations will vary.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix....so no special steps required for Intel Optane?

Comment: What's your question? What kind of "suggestions" or "pointers" are you looking for?

Comment: Do i need to do something special just because this machine has got Intel Optane...i heard/read that Intel optane won't work with dual boot or ubuntu(why it should not work...it's more at h/w level but definitely some setup is required)...to be on the better side...i am planning to put a PCIe NVME SSD and install ubuntu on that.