# How do I install Ubuntu 18 to use Intel Optane

Tags: lenovo

I have a Lenovo 330 IdeaPad with Intel Optane. The laptop came with Windows Pre Installed and was working surprisingly fast. 
I had to jump through a few hoops to get ubuntu running on the laptop (disable RST mode, Disable RT, gparted fix yada yada), but finally managed to get Linux installed.
I am wondering how I can get Linux to use Optane Memory. Is there any way to do this?
I heard about using bcache but can't seem to figure out how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Related: [Intel Optane Memory support for Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot on Dell i7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009710/intel-optane-memory-support-for-ubuntu-and-windows-10-dual-boot-on-dell-i7), [Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 10 on Intel Optane based computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990328/ubuntu-dual-boot-with-windows-10-on-intel-optane-based-computers) Also please use [full version numbers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17941/250300), there are _two_ [supported 18.x versions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases): 18.04 and 18.10.

Comment: So there's no way of using Optane with Ubuntu @melebius

Comment: Likely not (yet), I am sorry.